# Implementation of OpenGL libraries

Tags: c++, unix, opengl, x11, mesa

1. Who implement OpenGL libraries? (*.c files)
2. Whether there is cross-platform implementation of
   the library, not dependent of drivers?

Answer (score 1):

1. The GPU driver developers as part of their GPU drivers
2. Yes, but it will never be able to talk to GPUs and is limited to a software renderer: "Mesa llvmpipe" and "Mesa softpipe" are these implementations.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL is an open cross platform API STANDARD. The implementation is specific to the graphics card being used. On linux there is Mesa which was originally written as a software only implementation but is now used by Intel an AMD. Nvidia has its own solution.

Comment: AMD still supports their own proprietary fglrx, but they're moving fast to open sourcing fglrx and merging it into Mesa.